# How to detect the name of my current launcher?

Tags: launcher

My phone is Galaxy A5 2017

The Android updated automatically to version 8.0.0

My launcher app has some problems - I can't find the Skype icon and I really need it. I have to enter Google Play, to search "Skype" and then to push "Open" to start it - but that's really crap

I want to try another launcher (at this moment I'm running the default launcher app).

But in case the new launcher is even worse, I need to come back to the default launcher.

The problem is that I have no idea what's the name of my current launcher.

The Android OS should facilitate the users such essential information!

Comment: It is Samsung proprietary... Just install Nova and try that.

Comment: @acejavelin   -   Thanks but these things are getting out of control too easy, I really need a backup solution in case Nova doesn't work well on my device - I need to know the name of the default launcher so I can come back to it just in case.

Comment: There are dozens of good launchers you can pick from... Nova, Evie, ADW, Microsoft Launcher, Google Now Launcher, Action, Smart Launcher, Flick, Apex, AIO, Hyperion... How many options do you want? Google will get you a dozen lists of the "best" launchers for Android, there are many commonalities between them, take your pick. You can have multiple launchers installed.

Comment: Open Settings-Applications,-default applications, tap home screen and select launcher(if you have stock launcher it will be only one there, if you've installed other launchers, it will be available there. Selecting a launcher will set as default launcher.)

Comment: AFAIK, you *can't* (easily) uninstall Samsung's launcher as it's a system app. When you install 3rd-party launchers, you just add more selections for the launcher, but not necessarily replacing it wholly. Or in other words, you can have 10 launchers installed on the same phone at the same time, but only 1 active launcher.

Comment: That said, it's really strange if you can't find the Skype icon on the launcher. Maybe you're confusing app launcher with the home screen? But as of now, your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) and unclear of what you really want to solve (do you only want to know the name of the current launcher, or do you actually just want to get Skype icon on the current launcher?)

Comment: You may have accidentally hidden the Skype app. Go to Settings > Display > Home Screen > Hide Apps. Then ensure that Skype is not checked by accident.

Comment: @Rahul Gopi: Thank you sir! That's the answer to my question!! Settings - Applications - Default Applications (on my phone, this option is available using the three-button menu icon in the top-right corner) and then you get a list with the installed application launchers and you can select the default one. On my phone, the default application launcher is called **Samsung Experience Home**

Comment: @Andrew T. - I want many things but first of all I really wanted to know the name of my   launcher and this is the problem I wanted to solve first. For me, the Skype button issue is the second problem I wanted to solve - and I was mentioning it just to show that my question applies to real-life situations. I think the users should have access to the name of the launcher on their Android phone.

Comment: @Alex Myers  -  thanks, I tried that and no, it's not checked by accident. The Skype icon is not available on my home screen but it's also not available in the Applications list (the "Apps" button on my home screen). This is really strange. I can only find it in the list at the "Settings - Applications" but there I have no option to start it - the only options I got there is "Uninstall" and "Force stop". The only way I can start Skype is by entering the Play Store and searching for "Skype" and then push "Open", which is kind of a horrible solution

Comment: @Rahul Gopi  -  Can you add your answer as a regular answer to the question so I can vote and accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Settings->Applications->default applications.
Tap home screen and select your required launcher.
(if you have only stock launcher(for Samsung devices, it will be Samsung Experience Home), then there will be only one present, if you've installed other launchers like Nova etc. , then there will have a list of launchers available. Selecting any one launcher will set it as default launcher of device)

As AndrewT said: When you install 3rd-party launchers(from play store or using apk), you just add more selections for the launcher, but not necessarily replacing it wholly. Or in other words, you can have 10 launchers installed on the same phone at the same time, but only 1 active launcher.