# Cannot find apps

Tags: app-icons

I have the Samsung Galaxy S21 5G. So far, it has been great, however, this morning, I noticed my "games" folder has disappeared from my homescreen. I assumed I had accidentally deleted it while in my pocket or something. However, when I swipe up to look at installed apps, I cannot see them anywhere, and they aren't the only apps that have gone missing. If I search for them in the search bar, they appear and I can open them, but there are no icons anywhere. They appear on the apps list in the settings, and they appear as installed in the play store. So where are the icons?!

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your launcher. Try rto reset it (clear data & cache), or install another to check if you the apps will become visible again.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio which launcher? and where do I find the reset options?

Comment: And I can launch the apps fine if I search for them, so I wouldn't think it is the launcher

Comment: @Curious if your app launcher doesn't show the apps  out of a sudden but only shows them when searched for, then it means either the launcher offers app hiding feature and you somehow activated it and got those apps hid from launcher, or the launcher has a bug where it doesn't show some app icons at all. Try installing an another launcher app, such as Nova launcher, and see if the issue persists. Otherwise, clear data for your default launcher app. To know about it, see https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208963/96277

Comment: @Firelord I don't even know what the launcher is. The apps were showing fine up until today where they are now gone. So how do I clear the data and cache of this launcher? If I go to settings>apps, then it just gives me a list of apps

Comment: Samsung's default launcher is One UI Home. I must be listed among your apps when you go to Settings Apps. In case it is not listed, click the 3-dot menu and select Show system apps.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have found One UI Home, if I go to One UI Home settings > Hide apps, then the ones I am looking for don't even show up as an option?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have found where the icons are... They have gone to the game launcher. No idea how to stop that happening?

Comment: I don't know how the game launcher works as I don't own recent Samsung phones, so I can't advise on "how to stop that happening". Maybe if it is possible, you can disable if you never use it. Also try to place the apps ' shortcuts that disappeared back by using the drawer and placing them on your home screen